# mvn deploy to artifactory (large size artifact) gives broken pipe error

Tags: maven, artifactory

I am trying to deploy a large zip file (305 MB) to artifactory using the `mvn deploy` command, but i am getting broken pipe errors. I tried to upload the same file via the browser's "Deploy" button, and it worked fine.

Is there a setting that i can use to increase the socket timeout, or force maven/artifactory to wait until the package is uploaded?

Any help on how to resolve this is appreciated. Here are the log entries and stack trace:

```
May 09, 2016 11:16:32 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://mvnrepo.dev.xyz.myorg.net:8080
May 09, 2016 11:17:02 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://mvnrepo.dev.xyz.myorg.net:8080: Broken pipe
May 09, 2016 11:17:02 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://mvnrepo.dev.xyz.myorg.net:8080


Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.myorg.xyz.myapp:my-app-package:zip:0.1-svc20160509.151532-7 from/to xyz-service-snapshots (http://mvnrepo.dev.xyz.myorg.net:8080/artifactory/xyz-service-local): Broken pipe
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.put(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:311)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:662)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:557)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:533)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$PutTaskRunner.run(WagonTransporter.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute(WagonTransporter.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.put(WagonTransporter.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$PutTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.flushBuffer(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon$RequestEntityImplementation.writeTo(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:204)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestEntity(CPoolProxy.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:236)
```

Comment: I have this same issue between maven and artifactory, with the same error messages.  My file is 23MB, but it takes > 100 secs to almost upload.

Comment: I also see this issue when trying to upload a 10GB artifact to Nexus 3, and I have not been able to find a solution.. Hoping someone answers this question soon!

Comment: Confirming this issue; I consistently could not upload my 5 MB artifact to Artifactory. Looks like there's a default timeout of 30 seconds. Moving to faster wifi fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the issue by downgrade maven version from 3.5.2 to 3.0.4

Artifactory - open source 7.12.6

Answer (score 0):

#### General

A `Broken pipe` error typically indicates a network issue. Deploying an artifact on Artifactory may fail with this error either if you have network issues (lost packets during deployment) or if your Artifactory repository has ran out of space (physical memory on the repository). Check **Case 1** and **Case 2** for troubleshooting.

**Tip**: Run `mvn deploy -X`. The `-X` option will log further information related with your error (sets log-level to debug)

#### Case 1: Network Issue

##### Solution: Just retry it :)

##### Issue Details

Maven's [source code](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/0682a1cc0a7efc9110cdf4b7cc5a17497bd721e5/maven-embedder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/cli/transfer/AbstractMavenTransferListener.java#L195) seems to be using apache's `Validate` method, (throws an `IllegalArgumentException` on validation error) to compare and validate the size of the deployed artifact with the artifact that was built locally. Note: On `deploy`, maven builds the artifact locally, and then uploads it to the configured repository (could be Artifactory, Maven Central etc) which in your case is Artifactory.

The error should look like this:

```
[DEBUG] Failed to dispatch transfer event 'PUT PROGRESSED [ARTIFACT_SERVER_URL]/artifact.jar <> [LOCAL_PATH]/artifact.jar
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: progressed file size cannot be greater than size: 117964800 > 116927216
   at org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate.isTrue (Validate.java:158)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.AbstractMavenTransferListener$FileSizeFormat.formatProgress (AbstractMavenTransferListener.java:195)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.ConsoleMavenTransferListener.getStatus (ConsoleMavenTransferListener.java:117)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.ConsoleMavenTransferListener.transferProgressed (ConsoleMavenTransferListener.java:90)
   ...
```

#### Case 2: No space left on Artifactory repository

##### Solution: Free up space on Artifactory repository

##### Issue Details

For any erros related with deployment to artifactory, you can always check Artifactory's log from Web Application.
Just Navigate (from Sidebar) to `Admin/Advanced/System Logs`. Check for any error or warning in the log file.
An error related with the available space could be like the following:

```
2021-08-18 11:20:43,339 [http-nio-8081-exec-19] [WARN ] (o.a.w.s.RepoFilter  :252) - Sending HTTP error code 404: No space left on device
2021-08-18 11:20:43,346 [http-nio-8081-exec-16] [WARN ] (o.a.r.s.RepositoryServiceImpl:1739) - Datastore disk is too high: Warning limit: 80%, Used: 94%, Total: 688.01 GB, Used: 652.97 GB, Available: 35.04 GB
2021-08-18 11:20:43,346 [http-nio-8081-exec-16] [INFO ] (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:386) - Deploy to 'libs-snapshot-local:artifact.jar' Content-Length: 170019165
2021-08-18 11:20:44,086 [http-nio-8081-exec-16] [ERROR] (o.a.w.s.RepoFilter  :251) - Upload request of libs-snapshot-local:artifact.jar failed due to {}
java.io.IOException: No space left on device
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
   ...
```

In case you do identify such errors, try to remove some old artifacts to free up space, and retry your deployment later

**Tip**: It's a good practise to set some purging policies for old artifacts/snapshots on your Artifactory.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the broken pipe issue:

```
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://artifactory.....:443: Broken pipe (Write failed)
```

and it turned out this was masking a http 401 - ie authorisation issues.

You can see discussion of how this is caused by the Apache HttpClient libraries here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66326178/15441
and here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9176445/15441