# Getting Broken Pipe Write Failed while uploading artifacts to Artifactory

Tags: maven, artifactory, maven-deploy-plugin

I have around 5-6 components in my project but 3 of them have a size of around 60mb.
All other components succeed but when maven tries to deploy one of the large sized components it fails with a broken pipe error.
Can someone please help ? Is this related to any configuration or is it just my wifi speed ?

Comment: Please share the exact error you are getting and some additional information about your setup (Artifactory version, do you have an HTTP proxy in front of Artifactory). In addition there should be an error in the Artifactory log as well.
This is probably related to a timeout, how much time does it take from when you start uploading until you get the error?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37120293/mvn-deploy-to-artifactory-large-size-artifact-gives-broken-pipe-error

Answer (score 0):

This is the error that I got that appears to be a broken pipe similar to yours:

```
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://artifactory.....:443: Broken pipe (Write failed)
```

I investigated this - and it wasn't network issues at all. You can see the underlying error if you run

```
mvn -e -X ... [rest of maven parameters]
```

to show the underlying errors. When I ran this I saw authorisation failures. (That is - even though the main error looked like a networking issue - it was actually caused by bad passwords.)

The reason that this looks like a networking issue has to do with the Apache HttpClient library used by maven, and the way it uses sockets. You can see more information on this here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66326178/15441

and here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9176445/15441